# Употребление предлога в словосочетании "на/в воде"

Tags: предлоги

Как правильно сказать: *развлечения и эстафеты **на** воде* или ***в*** воде?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **Развлечения и эстафеты на воде.**

Здесь имеется в виду **обобщенное** значение существительного (развлечения, связанные с водой) или значение "**на поверхности воды**".

Предлог В связан **с погружением в воду**.

Примеры:

**Развлечения на воде** вроде бы все давно придуманы и всем давно известны. [Алексей Буланников. Для тех, кто в пути (2002) // «Домовой», 2002.06.04]

А потом они поехали в Купавну, пошли на озеро, и папа разрешил ему сидеть **в воде** сколько захочет. [Алексей Варламов. Купавна // «Новый Мир», 2000]

То есть он держался **на воде**, мог сделать несколько деревенских сажёнок в глубину, но тут же поворачивал назад, нащупывал ногами дно и выходил на берег. [Фазиль Искандер. Мой кумир (1965-1990)]

Comment: Ну, если развлекаются аквалангисты, то может быть и в воде :)

Comment: К аквалангистам нужен особый подход. У них и эстафеты бывают?

Comment: Можно устроить :) А если серьёзно, то развлечения и эстафеты в воде могут быть у детей (когда воды по колено).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь не в правильности/неправильности вопрос, а в том, что вы сами хотите сказать. Вопрос в выражении сути. 
На воде: 1) на поверхности самой воды; 2) на поверхности воды озера.  
В воде: 1) в воде, в водной среде; 2) в воде такого-то водоёма (или например, кто-то один в ванной с водой и развлекается, устраивая гонки).